# RegEx (.*?) any thing but one character

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to match something with a pattern amongst the lines of `/^(.*?)\/$`.
However, since `(.*?)` already matches `/` it also matches `anything///////////` but I only want it to match `anything/`.

Is there a nice way to exclude `/` from `(.*?)` or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [***negated* character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\/]`:

```
/^([^\/]*)\/$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bULmkh/2)

In PHP, you may avoid overescaping in the pattern using some other delimiter, say `~`:

```
$rx = '~^([^/]*)/$~';
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^\/]*)` - Group 1  capturing 0+ chars other than `/`
- `\/`  - a literal `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Note you do not need a lazy quantifier `*?` with this negated character class since it will be much more efficient with a greedy one, `*`.

Comment: Yip, awesome! Will accept as answer for additional information :)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a nice way to exclude / from (.*?) or alternative solutions?

Use a negated character class:

```
[^\/]*?
```